# Error after uploading app to the app store

Tags: ios, swift, app-store

For the record I have not touched any of the files listed below, all I did was compile, attempt to pull my hair out by uploading and then I got this error message:

> Invalid Swift Support - The files libswiftDarwin.dylib,
>   libswiftMetal.dylib, libswiftCoreAudio.dylib,
>   libswiftQuartzCore.dylib, libswiftos.dylib, libswiftObjectiveC.dylib,
>   libswiftDispatch.dylib, libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib,
>   libswiftCoreData.dylib, libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib,
>   libswiftUIKit.dylib, libswiftCoreMedia.dylib, libswiftCore.dylib,
>   libswiftFoundation.dylib, libswiftXCTest.dylib,
>   libswiftCoreImage.dylib aren’t at the expected location
>   /Payload/BeginerGuideDigFor.app/Frameworks. Move the file to the
>   expected location, rebuild your app using the current public (GM)
>   version of Xcode, and resubmit it.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the
>   corrected binary.

Honestly I wouldn't even know where to beign

So to answer one of the question, according to the part apple told me to go through my libraries are fine here is a pic of me running the code for that [image]

here is what I ran and below that is the result
[image]

UPDATE:

SOOOOO at this point I have now confounded the app support store, they cannot figure out why I am getting this error, they have asked me the same questions over and over, what version of Xcode, what version of Mac OS...  still no resolution.

Comment: Are you using Xcode 9 beta?

Comment: nope, I am using the latest release, I upgraded, I even tried uninstalling and them reinstalling.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

You mention a hair-pulling upload experience. But unless you have a build system/build scripts involved, normally the process is just Product>Archive and uploading from Window>Organizer (or using the Application Loader on an exported ipa from there). Are you doing anything different that may be corrupting the .ipa?

You might Export it for App Store, rename the .ipa file to .zip and unzip it. Right click on your app in the Payload directory, select Show Package Contents and look in your Frameworks directory for a clue. All of those files should be there. Do you have any Build Phase scripts that do anything with Frameworks?

UPDATE:

I just came across this Apple response to this type of issue in the Apple Developer Forums. That's a great resource for these types of things, by the way:

> It's likely you have a plain dylib outside of a framework somewhere,
>   which is only supported on macOS. Please review the Troubleshooting
>   section of Tech Note 2435 for more context.   If having a bare dylib
>   is indeed the cause of the problem, please file a bug for an error
>   message that clearly explains this.

Link: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/218019#218019

Comment: it hasn't been an easy process for whatever reason whatever could go wrong has so far and this has not made it any easier.  Apple support I find that to be lacking.

Comment: its a pretty simple app to start with, I mean there are some external links and embedded youtube videos but it's nothing out of the ordinary.  I just want to get this loaded so I can start on the next iteration, but I just keep hitting roadblocks...  the only thing I use to compile is xcode no outside scripts.

Comment: Getting all the provisioning profiles set up the first time and taking care of all the little things they validate on upload (new icons for new requirements, etc.) that you don't run into with dev builds can certainly be frustrating. But once the stars align, it should just be a few clicks. I came across an issue with the Xc9 uploading process where it will fail because it selects the wrong team if you're on multiple teams, but at least the Application Loader works.

Comment: have you been able to test on devices, or just in the simulator? If on devices, I'd think the swift support must be getting added correctly.

Comment: it works just fine on my iPhone no issue, so compile issues just this BS

Comment: Did you see my update with the link to a similar issue and Apple's response? That sounds like it, and the misleading error has nothing to do with Swift. See if you're including any dylibs in the app. Check the Project Settings>Build Phases>"Copy Bundled Resources", for example. Maybe there's something included that you didn't intend.

Comment: When I get home I will look at that, I'm not there just now, but if I waited till later to put this up the chance of my getting this going becomes slimmer.

Comment: Thank you, I had this error because I was using a dylib directly. Which works fine until you upload it on iTC.