# Invalid Swift Support

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, testflight

after uploading my app to testflight I get back a reply from Apple about issues with the app.

`Invalid Swift Support - The files libswiftDarwin.dylib, libswiftMetal.dylib, libswiftCoreAudio.dylib, libswiftQuartzCore.dylib, libswiftos.dylib, libswiftObjectiveC.dylib, libswiftDispatch.dylib, libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib, libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib, libswiftUIKit.dylib, libswiftCoreMedia.dylib, libswiftCore.dylib, libswiftFoundation.dylib, libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib, libswiftXCTest.dylib, libswiftCoreImage.dylib aren't at the expected location /Payload/*App.app/Frameworks. Move the file to the expected location, rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode, and resubmit it.`

After inspecting the .ipa I discovered that there is a directory called SwiftSupport and after doing a side by side comparison, I discovered that two frameworks are missing from the Payload/Frameworks but I am not using these frameworks (libCoreMedia and libXCTest. Does anyone have an idea why issue occurs. I am running Swift 4.2 in Xcode 10

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/q/48104942/1187415, https://stackoverflow.com/q/34602859/1187415 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/46366144/1187415 ?

Comment: @Martin R Yes I have. None of these seem to address my issue.

Comment: Make sure you haven't accidentally enabled core media or unit test feature in build setting.

Comment: Yes. I have not enabled them @MohamadSheikh

Answer (score 0):

This was an error caused by using an Xcode 9 project in Xcode 10.

Answer (score 0):

use below script remove arm64e from .app file

https://github.com/ndpiparava/Swift_StripArm64e